# Insert XML from Stored Procedure in C#

Tags: c#, sql-server, xml

I am trying to insert xml from a stored procedure into a table.

Not able to do it.

My approach :

```
CREATE PROCEDURE [dbo].[InsertXML]
    @xml XML
AS
BEGIN
      SET NOCOUNT ON;

      INSERT INTO [GpsCorporateCardIncentive](CCFrom, CCTo, CCIncentive)
         SELECT
             [Table].[Column].value('From[1]','DECIMAL(5,3)') AS CCFrom, 
             --ATTRIBUTE
             [Table].[Column].value('To[1]','DECIMAL(5,3)') AS CCTo, 
             --TAG
             [Table].[Column].value('IncentiveAmount[1]','DECIMAL(5,3)') AS CCIncentive --TAG
        FROM
            @xml.nodes('/ArrayOfIncentive/Invcentive') as [Table]([Column])
END
```

My xml looks like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-16"?>
<ArrayOfIncentive xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">
  <Incentive>
    <From>65.000</From>
    <To>89.000</To>
    <IncentiveAmount>25.000</IncentiveAmount>
  </Incentive>
  <Incentive>
    <From>67.000</From>
    <To>90.000</To>
    <IncentiveAmount>25.000</IncentiveAmount>
  </Incentive>
</ArrayOfIncentive>
```

C# Code :

```
public static void SaveXML(string filePath)
{
    string xml = File.ReadAllText(filePath);           

    using (SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(GetConnectionString()))
    {
        con.Open();

        SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("InsertXML", con);
        cmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@xml", xml);                

        cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
    }
}
```

But I don't see changes getting inserted in database.

I am not getting any error either.

Please help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> @xml.nodes('/ArrayOfIncentive/Invcentive') as Table

It can be a spelling error:
see, you have **Invcentive** in FROM statement, but in your XML you don't have such tags.